# T-SQL sort by most searched words containing in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search, sql-order-by

For example I executed following query:

```
Select 
    id, question 
From 
    tblQuestions
Where 
    question like '%Leave%'
    or question like '%Balances%'
    or question like '%Policy%'
```

It will return the rows where `question` contains any of the above 3 words. Is it possible that result sorted in a way that the question containing most words in above query should come first and so on (as shown in below table). 
(searched words may be more than three)

```
| id | question                                   |
|----|--------------------------------------------|
| 8  | Define the *policy* of *leave* *balances*? |     
| 2  | Why my *leave* *balance* is 0              |    
| 1  | What is *leave*?                           |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write the like conditions twice for each search term, you can use a cte with conditional aggrigation:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    Id int,
    Question varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,'What is leave?'),
(2,'Why my leave balance is 0?'),
(3, 'Where is my mind?'),
(8,'Define the policy of leave balances?')
```

The query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Id,
            Question, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN Question Like '%Leave%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
            SUM(CASE WHEN Question Like '%Balance%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
            SUM(CASE WHEN Question Like '%Policy%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As MatchCount
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY Id, Question
)

SELECT  Id,
        Question
FROM CTE 
WHERE MatchCount > 0
ORDER BY MatchCount DESC
```

Results:

```
Id  Question
8   Define the policy of leave balances?
2   Why my leave balance is 0?
1   What is leave?
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `Full Test Search` is designed for. Besides, it can match different grammar forms i.e. `balances` and `balance`. You can still try to use regular syntax as in following snippet:

```
SELECT id, question
FROM tblQuestions
WHERE 
    question LIKE '%Leave%'
    OR question LIKE '%Balance%'
    OR question LIKE '%Policy%'
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN question LIKE '%Leave%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN question LIKE '%Balance%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN question LIKE '%Policy%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```